# Gnome tweaks keyboard layout issue [20.04]

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweaks

I am using gnome-tweak-tools to set the way of switching keyboard layout to Ctrl+Shift.
After some random time, even without rebooting, it stops working, even though in gnome tweaks the option is checked.
Any ideas?

Comment: I also have this with capslock as ctrl. Have you solved?

Comment: I set switching the keyboard layout to Ctrl+Ctrl or Shift+Shift, but it doesn't work at all. :/